# Find in (HTML) Page Script

Tags: html, find

I would like to add a Find box in an html page that has a long list of names. This would be similar to a browser Find in page feature.  I will be using this on iOS devices within a UIWebView and so there is no Find in Page feature.

Linda

Comment: Well, it's still understandable enough. You can use Javascript?

Comment: Sorry for not phrasing it as a question.  I did not know if it was a browser only feature (built-in to the browser) or if it is something that could be added via JavaScript to a page. From Pekka's answer (question) it appears then that it is possible with JavaScript. Can someone point me to a JavaScript solution to creating a find feature on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here.
http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm